# How to query certain metrics from tik tok report api in python?

Tags: python, tiktok

Hi I am trying to get additional metrics such as reach, video view up to 50%, video view up to 100% and url link per ad. However I am having a hard time finding the documentation to get such items.

currently this is my code that runs

```
endDate ="2022-05-01"
def tiktok(endDate):
    dftiktok=pd.DataFrame()
    ACCESS_TOKEN = "xxxxxxxx"
    PATH = "/open_api/v1.2/reports/integrated/get/"
    advertiser_id = "xxxxx"
    service_type = 'AUCTION'
    data_level= "AUCTION_CAMPAIGN"
    dimensions_list = ["campaign_id",'stat_time_day']
    dimensions = json.dumps(dimensions_list)
    start_date = str(endDate) 
    end_date =str(endDate)
    metrics_list = ["campaign_name",'objective_type',"spend", "impressions",'app_install','registration','clicks']
    metrics = json.dumps(metrics_list)
    order_field = 'stat_time_day'
    page = 1
    page_size =1000

    url = f"https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.2/reports/integrated/get/?advertiser_id={advertiser_id}&service_type={service_type}&report_type=BASIC&data_level={data_level}&dimensions={dimensions}&data_level=AUCTION_AD&metrics={metrics}&start_date={start_date}&end_date={end_date}&order_field=impressions&page={page}&page_size={page_size}&order_field={order_field}"
    headers = {
            "Access-Token": ACCESS_TOKEN,
    }
    rsp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(rsp)
    rows = pd.json_normalize(rsp.json(),record_path=[['data','list']],errors='ignore')
    dftiktok=dftiktok.append(rows)
    return dftiktok
```

If anyone can refer a refrence or tell me how to get those items.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add data to your request:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import json


def get_tiktok_data(access_token):
    request_url = 'https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.2/reports/integrated/get/'
    headers = {
        'access-token': access_token,
        'content_type': 'application/json'
    }
    metrics = [
        'campaign_name', 'spend', 'cpc', 'cpm', 'impressions', 'clicks', 'ctr', 'reach', 'cost_per_1000_reached', 'conversion', 'conversion_rate', 'currency', 'sales_lead', 'total_sales_lead_value', 'skan_sales_lead'
    ]
    dimensions = [
        'campaign_id',
    ]
    date_from = date.today().replace(day=1)
    date_to = (date_from + timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
    data = {
        'advertiser_id': client.int_id,
        'data_level': 'AUCTION_CAMPAIGN',
        'report_type': 'BASIC',
        'dimensions': json.dumps(dimensions),
        'metrics': json.dumps(metrics),
        'start_date': date_from,
        'end_date': date_to,
        'lifetime': 'false',
        'page_size': 1000,
    }
    resp = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers, data=data)
    result = resp.json()
    print(result)
    return result
```

The code was torn out in pieces, some inaccuracies are possible, but it should work.

Comment: please, could you share the TikTok API documentation link?

Comment: I answer to me 
https://ads.tiktok.com/marketing_api/docs?id=1738864739862530